# What does "Position in a stream" mean in C#?

Tags: c#

I have trouble to understand the word "**Position of a stream**". My question is somehow related to the concept of the stream method **Seek()**; it is kind confusing to me what this method does, they say its purpose is to set the position of the stream to a given value but yet its name describes the seek operation not set operation. Does anyone understand clearly what these two words are for and how they work together? Thanx

Comment: It is not the "Position of a stream" but the "Position _in_ a stream".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about a file as a sequence of bytes, and a stream as a view over that sequence, with a cursor marking the current position - so as you read data, the cursor is advanced. The `Position` property is simply the position of that cursor. So when you open a stream it's typically at 0, and as you read it increases. For seekable streams, you can "rewind" to the start of the stream with

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

or maybe skip 10 bytes using:

```
stream.Position += 10;
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

A [stream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_stream) is basically a sequence of bytes - the position is the point in the sequence that the stream is in.

The point of `Seek` is to "jump" to a location in the stream - a specific index (aka Position), similar to seeks done in a hard drive. With `Seek` you can specify an *offset* to start seeking from, so how many bytes to "jump".

Answer (score 1):

The following 2 statements do exactly the same:

```
s.Position = 100;
s.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

And they both determine the position (as a bytecount) where the next Read or Write will occur.

The `Seek()` name is very ancient.

Comment: Hey Henk! Can you explain to me what the SeekOrigin is all about? Say s.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.End) ; will it set the cursor starting from the end of the stream ?

Comment: Yes. I think those names a re pretty self-describing. You will very rarely need them (and therefore Seek() ). Just use `Positon`.

Answer (score 0):

I actually agree that, at first glance, `Seek` is not the best name for what it does. `SeekAndSet` or `SeekAndMove` would make more sense to me because that is what the method does - it seeks the position you want in the stream and sets the cursor to that position.

However, when you think of [Seek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seek_time#Seek_time) in Computer Science terms in relation to hard disk drives it becomes obvious what this method does. It seeks and moves to the position.

Answer (score 0):

Also, for the record with `NAudio`, this used to be `stream.GetPosition()` as well. It's since changed to just `stream.Position`